# How to refresh and then read the data from Pivot Table using Apache POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi, pivot-table

I wanna dynamically supply some source data for Pivot Table using Apache POI which is not a problem at all.

When it comes to refreshing the Pivot Table with new data it seems like POI doesn't have the ability to refresh it in runtime and then read the generated data produced by Pivot Table, is that possible to achieve by Apache POI?

```
XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Test SHEET");
XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = sheet.createPivotTable(new AreaReference("'Test 1'!$A$1:$S$1048575", SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007), new CellReference("A1"));

pivotTable.addRowLabel(9); // name
//Sum up the second column
pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM, 6); // weight
// NEED TO REFRESH AND THEN READ THE SECOND COLUMN WHICH IS ABOVE
```

Comment: I didn't find any solution to refresh/read data from the Pivot Table instead wrote the code to replace the Pivot table

Comment: I am facing same issue, but I can't replace pivot table